# Issue On Getting jQuery Post Result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to run this simple Ajax Post example like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.post("test.php",
        {
          name:"Hello Ajax"
        },
        function(data){
          $("p").html(data);
        }
      );
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and PHP (test.php) as:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo '<a>'.$name.'</a>';
?>
```

No error message but not getting any result back! can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you clicking your `button` element to call the AJAX? I dont see a `button` element in the above HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple change, added button element in your markup. Click it and it should work:

```
<body>
<button>Click Me</button>
  <p></p>
</body>
```

Your javascript is looking for the button element on which when clicked, will trigger the ajaxcall in test.php

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

By clicking the button, it will display `Hello Ajax`, the echo from the test.php and the one that you've send.

```
 $.post("test.php",
        {
          name:"Hello Ajax"
        },
```

Comment: Thanks kimbarcelona , what a silly mistake I was doing!